# C# XMLreader, not going into if statement to read element

Tags: c#, xml, gps, xmlreader, gpx

I have a C# program that reads a gpx file,
I place every element in a variable and at the end I put all thos element in an object.
for al these elements I have functions, so each function reads a tag, I do that with this if statement:

```
        public double GetEle(XmlReader reader)
    {

            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "ele"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble()));
                double value = reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                return Math.Round(value, 2);
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

the problem is that my program never goes into that if statement (my messageBox doesn't pop up)
however if I place that if statement inside this loop ↓ .
Then my program goes into all my if statement.

```
                while (reader.Read())
            {}
```

My problem is that I use while (reader.Read()) in the function that calls my GetEle() function. So I don't want to loop throught my GetEle() function, only run it one time:

```
        public List<GPXDataObject> Extract(string path)
    {
        if (path == String.Empty)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("path");
        }
        if (path == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }
        List<GPXDataObject> gpxDataList = new List<GPXDataObject>();

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                List<double> coordinates = Coordinates(reader);
                double lat = coordinates[0];
                double lon = coordinates[1];
                double ele = GetEle(reader);
                DateTime date = GetDate(reader);
                float speed = GetSpeed(reader);
                float azimuth = GetAzimuth(reader);
                GPXDataObject gpxDataObject = new GPXDataObject(lat, lon, ele, date, speed, azimuth);
                gpxDataList.Add(gpxDataObject);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        return gpxDataList;
    }
```

I have this problem in all my functions, if I use while(reader.read()) the function works, but loops throught my whole gpx file and returns the last element. If I don't include the while loop my program never goes into my if statement.

- why doesn't my GetEle function work without the while loop? (I have the while loop in my main function)
- How to fix it?

Here is a sample of my xml data:

```
<trk>
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="47.021897" lon="9.965247">
        <ele>811.90</ele>
        <time>2015-02-18T07:17:25.01Z</time>
        <extensions>
            <gte:gps speed="2.1" azimuth="42.9"/>
        </extensions>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="47.021896" lon="9.965999">
        <ele>812.19</ele>
        <time>2015-02-18T07:17:25.21Z</time>
        <extensions>
            <gte:gps speed="2.0" azimuth="44.3"/>
        </extensions>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="47.021890" lon="9.965241">
        <ele>812.53</ele>
        <time>2015-02-18T07:17:25.41Z</time>
        <extensions>
            <gte:gps speed="1.5" azimuth="48.0"/>
        </extensions>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="47.021885" lon="9.965238">
        <ele>812.49</ele>
        <time>2015-02-18T07:17:25.61Z</time>
        <extensions>
            <gte:gps speed="1.2" azimuth="58.7"/>
        </extensions>
    </trkpt>
</trkseg>
```

I hope I explained my problem clear enough and someone will take the time to read through it and help me. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlReader` is forward-only reading, and it only advances when you call `.Read()` - so here's what your program is currently doing (assuming the `Coordinates` constructor that takes an `XmlReader` is meant to parse the `trkpt` element):

1. Create Reader for the file
2. For every single node (element, text, attribute) in the file, run the code that tries to get coordinates, elements, and create your `GPXDataObject`.
3. Return a list of these partial GPXDataObjects (one loop got lat/long, one loop got speed, one loop got time, etc.).

Here's more along the lines of what you probably want:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("trkpt")) // advance the reader to the next trkpt element
    {
        List<double> coordinates = Coordinates(reader);
        double lat = coordinates[0];
        double lon = coordinates[1];
        reader.ReadToFollowing("ele"); // reader.Read() might work here, depending on what state Coordinates left the reader in
        double ele = GetEle(reader);
        reader.ReadToFollowing("time");
        DateTime date = GetDate(reader);
        reader.ReadToFollowing("extensions"); // note: it's not clear what GetSpeed and GetAzimuth need - do they expect the reader to be on the extensions element or the gte:gps element?
        float speed = GetSpeed(reader);
        float azimuth = GetAzimuth(reader);
        GPXDataObject gpxDataObject = new GPXDataObject(lat, lon, ele, date, speed, azimuth);
        gpxDataList.Add(gpxDataObject);
    }         
}
```

That should at least get you started.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem :D.

This is my first time using the XML reader so I don't know all the functions, reader.ReadToFollowing() was exactly what I need.

Comment: It's very powerful, but can be a bit confusing at first.  Best of luck.